# How can I merge multiple workbooks into one?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Say I have a directory with the following files:

- Workbook1.xlsx (Contains Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3)
- Workbook2.xlsx (Contains Sheet4 and Sheet5)
- Workbook3.xlsx (Contains Sheet 6)

How can I create a master workbook that contains all spreadsheets?

i.e., MasterWorkbook.xlsx (Contains Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4, Sheet5 and Sheet6)

Thanks,

Ignacio

Comment: I have voted to move this question, however, @iggymoran, if you would like to add some notes on coding, it probably will not get the rest of the close votes.

Answer (score 1):

Ignacio,

There is more than one way to do it, you'll need to pick the one based on what you're trying to achieve.

**Method 1** (using data source connection): A little bit more complex, but worth if you have a well defined structure in your files. Is required to name ranges in each sheet. You can obviously name a whole sheet as a range, but as smaller the range, the better performance you'll have.

- Open *Workbooks1.sheet1*
- Select the whole source data you want
- Name this range (by clicking on the upper-left text space that contains the data address, i.e. *A1*

  Step 1 is done, you have a named range with the source data you want
- Now, go for the MasterWorkbook
- Data Ribbon (I assume you're using Excel 2007, due to the xlsx files)
- Connections
- Add
- Seach more...
- Connect to a new data source
- DSN ODBC
- Excel Files
- select your Workbook1 file
- Select the range you defined previously
- Finish
- Close

Step 2 is done; you have a data source connection to the data at spreadsheet1

- Click in Existing connections
- Add the source you created

Done, you have a link to the data at worksheet1.sheet1

**Method 2** (using cell level relationship): More straightforward, however I believe that's slower and more error prone.

- Open Workbooks1
- Open MasterWorkbook
- On Masterworkbook.Sheet1.A1, type "=" [enter]
- Click on Workbooks1.Sheet1.A1 [enter]
- Take a look on the address generated; it's a reference to the Workbooks1.xlsx
- Remove the $ from $A$1 and drag the formula. Initially for the columns, and then for the rows
- Voilà, you have a relationship between the Workbooks

Notice that you'll only be able to see the data in MasterWorkbook; any change in Workbook cells with pointers will raplace that formula.

Edit: There are other solutions as well, as you can see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830841/merge-excel-files-into-one/830869#830869)

Answer (score 1):

Ron de Bruin has created a fabulous Windows plugin for merging Excel worksheets, called 
RDBMerge. Instructions can be found here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/merge.htm. It worked flawlessly for me, merging xlsx files in Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want an automatic way to do it (i.e. a macro or similar), or do you only need to do it once?

If you only need to do it once, then you can just [move all of the worksheets to the same workbook (file)](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/move-or-copy-a-worksheet-HP001217035.aspx).